# How to use FasterXML/jackson-databind to deserialize List<Map> as List

Tags: java, arrays, json, fasterxml

I spent some time googling try to figure out how to deserialize this json as a `List<Link>`. I know it's `List<Map<String, Link>>`. So I would like know if anyone knows if it's possible do it that way.

```cs
public class Link {
    private String type;
    private String url;
}
```

```js
"links": [
    {
       "link": {
              "type": "category",
              "url": "http://compa...."
           }
    }, {
       "link": {
              "type": "xml",
              "url": "http://san..."
           }
    }
 ],
```